# Decorator with abstraction, dont get decorated value properly

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Im trying to do [Decorator Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) and it is what i got:

My base class is an `abstract Worker` class:

```
public abstract class Worker
{
    public float Salary { get; set; }
    public abstract float CountSalary();
}
```

`Worker` is a base class for `Driver`:

```
public class Driver : Worker
{
    public float Salary { get; set; }
    public override float CountSalary() => Salary = 3000;
    //for testing i just hard coded '3000' value
}
```

My Decorator is an `abstract Bonus` class. It decorating worker's salary with bonuses.

```
public abstract class Bonus : Worker
{
    public Bonus(Worker worker) => this.worker = worker;
    public override float CountSalary() => worker.Salary;
    protected Worker worker { get; private set; }
}

public class AmountBonus : Bonus
{
    public AmountBonus(Worker worker) : base(worker: worker){ }
    public override float CountSalary() => base.worker.Salary + 200;
}
```

I make a call of a `Decorator` in this way in my code:

```
Worker w = new AmountBonus(new Driver());
```

And instead of `3200`, new `Salary = 200`. Could you tell me, when i make a mistake and i dont get predicted `Salary = 3200`? Why when i make call like this:

```
Worker w = new AmountBonus(new AmountBonus(new Driver()));
```

My `Salary` dont stack to 3400 value?

Comment: You're `AmountBonus` class doesn't inherit from `Driver`, and thereby the Salary you're setting on the Driver doesn't affect your Amount Bonus

Comment: If I understood you intentions then: 1. `Bonus` should not inherit from `Worker`. 2. This line `public override float CountSalary() => Salary = 3000;` in the Driver class should be replaced by a CTOR instead.

Comment: That `Salary = 3000` is for testing only. Is it way to get that `Salary` from `Driver` by abstract `Worker` class?

Comment: Shouldn't you declare in the abstract class `public virtual float Salary { get; set; }`?

Comment: When `Salary` is `virutal` in `abstract worker, still get `Slaary = 200`

Comment: Whate about making an `Interface` ? But then, i wont have `Salary` property there

Comment: (unrelated) Hate to be "that guy" again: Do not use floating point types for monetary amounts.

Comment: Haha thanks, i know it should be decimal, but in my case, float will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some modifications to your code :

```
 public abstract class Worker
{
    public abstract float Salary { get; } 
}

public class Driver : Worker
{
       public class Driver : Worker
      {
    float _salary = 0;
    public Driver(float Salary)
    {
        _salary = Salary;
    } 
    public override float Salary { get { return _salary; } } 
    //for testing i just hard coded '3000' value
   }

}

public abstract class Bonus : Worker
{
    public Bonus(Worker worker) => this.worker = worker; 
    protected Worker worker { get; private set; }
}

public class AmountBonus : Bonus
{
    public AmountBonus(Worker worker) : base(worker: worker) { }
    public override float Salary
    {
        get
        {
            return worker.Salary +200;
        }
    }

}


  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var driver = new Driver(3200);

        Console.WriteLine(driver.Salary);
        var driverSalWithBonus = new AmountBonus(driver);
        Console.WriteLine(driverSalWithBonus.Salary);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Then main problem with your code was CountSalary method was not called anywhere and its not required. The second problem was Salary should abstract so that it can be overwritten in the child classes.

Comment: Working on property instead of method that returning value is a way that `Decorator` design pattern allows to?

Comment: Your way to do it work, but what when we want to add another bonus like  `Worker w = new AmountBonus(new AmountBonus(new Driver()));`?

Comment: I would hope so. In the background a Property is nothing more than a shorthand way of writing a private field with (depending on get, set, public, private combo) methods setting and returning that field. Much like how in Java you manually write those. The compiler then just replaces the `worker.Salary` part with `worker.Salary.Get()`, check the Debugger when a null reference occurs

Comment: Its not mandatory to use property instead of method, but in your code I found little complexity with CountSalary which was not even required, that's why I removed it. You can use method or property whatever you want but that should be abstract in the base class and overridden in the drived classes.

Also Worker w = new AmountBonus(new AmountBonus(new Driver())); this perfectly works for me let me know where you are facing issue with it.

Comment: The thing is, that i want to use `Salary {set;}` from my `Driver` class. How to make it possible in your case? Thats why i want to wrapping `Salary` property into `CountSalary()` method

Comment: Simply add a parameterized constructor in the driver class and assign salary into a local variable and return that variable from Salary Property. I have updated my code for the same.